# javassist.CannotCompileException for dynamic agent

Tags: java, java-8, javassist

I am trying to dynamically load a javaagent using javassist 3.27.0-GA for java 8.
I have a class

```
package com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.handler;

public class Lemon {

    public static void printLemon() {
        System.out.println("Lemon");
    }

}
```

Then inside the agentmain method of my Agent, I use `ClassPool.getDefault()` to get the default class pool and find the class I wish to transform. I get a declared method and then call

```
ctMethod.insertBefore("com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.handler.Lemon.printLemon();");
```

this results in the following stacktrace:

```
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]: javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: com$github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.handler.Lemon
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:806)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:766)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.agent.Agent.lambda$buildTransformer$0(Agent.java:31)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.agent.Agent$$Lambda$2938/1745973473.invoke(Unknown Source)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.transformer.MCTransformer.transform(MCTransformer.kt:20)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.agent.Agent.agentmain(Agent.java:19)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:411)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]: Caused by: compile error: no such class: com$github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.handler.Lemon
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:479)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:422)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:329)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:711)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:170)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:49)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:266)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:360)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:53)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:578)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:786)
[11:29:56] [Attach Listener/INFO]: [STDERR]:    ... 15 more
```

Calling `System.out.println(String.valueOf(ctMethod.getDeclaringClass().getClassPool().getOrNull("com.github.thamid_gamer.agenttest.handler.Lemon") == null));` prints out `false`.
I have not changed the classpool's classpath with any methods. What should I do to let javassist find my classes?

EDIT:
minified test which still doesn't work:

```java
package com.github.thamid_gamer.agent;

import javassist.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Agent {

    private static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer((loader, className, classBeingRedefined, protectionDomain, classfileBuffer) -> {
            if ("bec".equals(className)) { // transforming class in default package
                ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
                try {
                    CtClass ctClass = classPool.getCtClass("bec");
                    CtMethod ctMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("j");
                    ctMethod.insertBefore("com.github.thamid_gamer.agent.Lemon.printLemon();");

                    byte[] bytecode = ctClass.toBytecode();
                    ctClass.detach();

                    return bytecode;
                } catch (NotFoundException | CannotCompileException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }, true);
        try {
            instrumentation.retransformClasses(Class.forName("bec"));
        } catch (UnmodifiableClassException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.github.thamid_gamer.agent;

public class Lemon {

    public static void printLemon() {
        System.out.println("Lemon");
    }

}
```

a similar stacktrace occurs with a $ after the com

Comment: the error is clear to me: `no such class: com$github...`. `com$github` seems like a weird package... How is that class resolved, did you make a typo somewhere? -> [mre]

Comment: trying with a test still produced com$github, edited main post